# Custom highlights not working in visual splits

Tags: vimrc, syntax-highlighting, whitespace

I'm a tabs kind of guy, so I highlight leading and trailing white spaces with the following commands in my `.vimrc`:

```
highlight whiteSpace_trailing ctermbg=red guibg=red
highlight whiteSpace_leading  ctermbg=red guibg=red
match  whiteSpace_trailing /\s\+$/
2match whiteSpace_leading /^ \+/
```

This works fine when I have only one window open. However, when opening a second window with visual splits for example, these specs are not taken into account. Any idea why and how to fix it?

Comment: This isn't a direct answer to your question, but have you looked at the `listchars` option? It can highlight whitespace for you. I have the following in my `vimrc`: `set list listchars=tab:>-,trail:·`. This will make it show tabs as `>---` and trailing spaces as `·`.

Comment: @Tumbler41 It's not the first time I see someone mention it but first time I actually try it. It does seems to work in visual splits as well. This may be an alternative as I find the red highlighting a bit too agressive sometimes. I found another post on SE that states that the combination of list and listchars only works on trailing white space but not leading spaces

Comment: You can also see spaces if you add `space:·` to the list (separated by a comma of course). Of course this is all spaces, not leading spaces.

Comment: matches are window local. So you need to put this into a WinEnter or BufWinEnter autocommand.